# How to fix this error type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I make the request with Flutter 2.0 since the service is too large an array so when it makes the request generate an error, put the JsonSerilizable, but nothing happens, I don't know if it's because of the api or something I don't know

```
  Future<List<RedData>?> getData() async {
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(
        'some Api'));

    try {
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {

        final jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
        List<RedData> responsen = jsonResponse.map((job) => RedData.fromJson(job)).toList();
    
        return responsen; 
    
      } else {
        throw Exception('Fallo al cargar el Api');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
}
```

This is a model

```
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'ModelRedData.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class RedData {
 
   RedData({
    required this.dot11Device,
    required this.kismetDeviceBaseBasicCryptSet,
    required this.kismetDeviceBaseBasicTypeSet,
    required this.kismetDeviceBaseChannel,
    required this.kismetDeviceBaseCommonname,
    required this.kismetDeviceBaseCrypt,
    required this.kismetDeviceBaseDatasize,
    required this.kismetDeviceBaseDatasizeRrd,
    required this.kismetDeviceBaseFirstTime,
    required this.kismetDeviceBaseFreqKhzMap,
    required this.kismetDeviceBaseFrequency,
    required this.kismetDeviceBaseKey,
    required this.kismetDeviceBaseLastTime,
    required this.kismetDeviceBaseMacaddr,
    required this.kismetDeviceBaseManuf,
    required this.kismetDeviceBaseModTime,
    required this.kismetDeviceBaseName,
    required this.kismetDeviceBaseNumAlerts,
    required this.kismetDeviceBasePacketsCrypt,
    required this.kismetDeviceBasePacketsData,
    required this.kismetDeviceBasePacketsError,
    required this.kismetDeviceBasePacketsFiltered,
    required this.kismetDeviceBasePacketsLlc,
    required this.kismetDeviceBasePacketsRrd,
    required this.kismetDeviceBasePacketsRx,
    required this.kismetDeviceBasePacketsTotal,
    required this.kismetDeviceBasePacketsTx,
    required this.kismetDeviceBasePhyname,
    required this.kismetDeviceBaseRelatedDevices,
    required this.kismetDeviceBaseSeenby,
    required this.kismetDeviceBaseType,
    required this.kismetServerUuid,
  });
  Dot11Device dot11Device;
  int kismetDeviceBaseBasicCryptSet;
  int kismetDeviceBaseBasicTypeSet;
  String kismetDeviceBaseChannel;
  String kismetDeviceBaseCommonname;
  String kismetDeviceBaseCrypt;
  int kismetDeviceBaseDatasize;
  KismetDeviceBaseRrd kismetDeviceBaseDatasizeRrd;
  int kismetDeviceBaseFirstTime;
  KismetDeviceBase kismetDeviceBaseFreqKhzMap;
  int kismetDeviceBaseFrequency;
  String kismetDeviceBaseKey;
  int kismetDeviceBaseLastTime;
  String kismetDeviceBaseMacaddr;
  @JsonKey(name: "kismet.device.base.manuf")
  String kismetDeviceBaseManuf;
  int kismetDeviceBaseModTime;
  String kismetDeviceBaseName;
  int kismetDeviceBaseNumAlerts;
  int kismetDeviceBasePacketsCrypt;
  int kismetDeviceBasePacketsData;
  int kismetDeviceBasePacketsError;
  int kismetDeviceBasePacketsFiltered;
  int kismetDeviceBasePacketsLlc;
  KismetDeviceBaseRrd kismetDeviceBasePacketsRrd;
  int kismetDeviceBasePacketsRx;
  int kismetDeviceBasePacketsTotal;
  int kismetDeviceBasePacketsTx;
  String kismetDeviceBasePhyname;
  KismetDeviceBase kismetDeviceBaseRelatedDevices;
  List<KismetDeviceBaseSeenby> kismetDeviceBaseSeenby;
  String kismetDeviceBaseType;
  String kismetServerUuid;

  factory RedData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => RedData(
        dot11Device: Dot11Device.fromJson(json["dot11.device"]),
        kismetDeviceBaseBasicCryptSet:
            json["kismet.device.base.basic_crypt_set"],
        kismetDeviceBaseBasicTypeSet: json["kismet.device.base.basic_type_set"],
        kismetDeviceBaseChannel: json["kismet.device.base.channel"],
        kismetDeviceBaseCommonname: json["kismet.device.base.commonname"],
        kismetDeviceBaseCrypt: json["kismet.device.base.crypt"],
        kismetDeviceBaseDatasize: json["kismet.device.base.datasize"],
        kismetDeviceBaseDatasizeRrd: KismetDeviceBaseRrd.fromJson(
            json["kismet.device.base.datasize.rrd"]),
        kismetDeviceBaseFirstTime: json["kismet.device.base.first_time"],
        kismetDeviceBaseFreqKhzMap:
            KismetDeviceBase.fromJson(json["kismet.device.base.freq_khz_map"]),
        kismetDeviceBaseFrequency: json["kismet.device.base.frequency"],
        kismetDeviceBaseKey: json["kismet.device.base.key"],
        kismetDeviceBaseLastTime: json["kismet.device.base.last_time"],
        kismetDeviceBaseMacaddr: json["kismet.device.base.macaddr"],
        kismetDeviceBaseManuf: json["kismet.device.base.manuf"],
        kismetDeviceBaseModTime: json["kismet.device.base.mod_time"],
        kismetDeviceBaseName: json["kismet.device.base.name"],
        kismetDeviceBaseNumAlerts: json["kismet.device.base.num_alerts"],
        kismetDeviceBasePacketsCrypt: json["kismet.device.base.packets.crypt"],
        kismetDeviceBasePacketsData: json["kismet.device.base.packets.data"],
        kismetDeviceBasePacketsError: json["kismet.device.base.packets.error"],
        kismetDeviceBasePacketsFiltered:
            json["kismet.device.base.packets.filtered"],
        kismetDeviceBasePacketsLlc: json["kismet.device.base.packets.llc"],
        kismetDeviceBasePacketsRrd: KismetDeviceBaseRrd.fromJson(
            json["kismet.device.base.packets.rrd"]),
        kismetDeviceBasePacketsRx: json["kismet.device.base.packets.rx"],
        kismetDeviceBasePacketsTotal: json["kismet.device.base.packets.total"],
        kismetDeviceBasePacketsTx: json["kismet.device.base.packets.tx"],
        kismetDeviceBasePhyname: json["kismet.device.base.phyname"],
        kismetDeviceBaseRelatedDevices: KismetDeviceBase.fromJson(
            json["kismet.device.base.related_devices"]),
        kismetDeviceBaseSeenby: List<KismetDeviceBaseSeenby>.from(
            json["kismet.device.base.seenby"]
                .map((x) => KismetDeviceBaseSeenby.fromJson(x))),
        kismetDeviceBaseType: json["kismet.device.base.type"],
        kismetServerUuid: json["kismet.server.uuid"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "dot11.device": dot11Device.toJson(),
        "kismet.device.base.basic_crypt_set": kismetDeviceBaseBasicCryptSet,
        "kismet.device.base.basic_type_set": kismetDeviceBaseBasicTypeSet,
        "kismet.device.base.channel": kismetDeviceBaseChannel,
        "kismet.device.base.commonname": kismetDeviceBaseCommonname,
        "kismet.device.base.crypt": kismetDeviceBaseCrypt,
        "kismet.device.base.datasize": kismetDeviceBaseDatasize,
        "kismet.device.base.datasize.rrd": kismetDeviceBaseDatasizeRrd.toJson(),
        "kismet.device.base.first_time": kismetDeviceBaseFirstTime,
        "kismet.device.base.freq_khz_map": kismetDeviceBaseFreqKhzMap.toJson(),
        "kismet.device.base.frequency": kismetDeviceBaseFrequency,
        "kismet.device.base.key": kismetDeviceBaseKey,
        "kismet.device.base.last_time": kismetDeviceBaseLastTime,
        "kismet.device.base.macaddr": kismetDeviceBaseMacaddr,
        "kismet.device.base.manuf": kismetDeviceBaseManuf,
        "kismet.device.base.mod_time": kismetDeviceBaseModTime,
        "kismet.device.base.name": kismetDeviceBaseName,
        "kismet.device.base.num_alerts": kismetDeviceBaseNumAlerts,
        "kismet.device.base.packets.crypt": kismetDeviceBasePacketsCrypt,
        "kismet.device.base.packets.data": kismetDeviceBasePacketsData,
        "kismet.device.base.packets.error": kismetDeviceBasePacketsError,
        "kismet.device.base.packets.filtered": kismetDeviceBasePacketsFiltered,
        "kismet.device.base.packets.llc": kismetDeviceBasePacketsLlc,
        "kismet.device.base.packets.rrd": kismetDeviceBasePacketsRrd.toJson(),
        "kismet.device.base.packets.rx": kismetDeviceBasePacketsRx,
        "kismet.device.base.packets.total": kismetDeviceBasePacketsTotal,
        "kismet.device.base.packets.tx": kismetDeviceBasePacketsTx,
        "kismet.device.base.phyname": kismetDeviceBasePhyname,
        "kismet.device.base.related_devices":
            kismetDeviceBaseRelatedDevices.toJson(),
        "kismet.device.base.seenby":
            List<dynamic>.from(kismetDeviceBaseSeenby.map((x) => x.toJson())),
        "kismet.device.base.type": kismetDeviceBaseType,
        "kismet.server.uuid": kismetServerUuid,
      };
}
```

When I go to show the data I have this error

'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<dynamic,dynamic>? data;
```

This would allow the data to be null.